# Edge window not focusing when opening an external link

Tags: spaces, macos

I have an odd problem with Edge on Mac, when opening a link from a different app, say mail, the link is opened with Edge, but the window is not focused. I use multiple spaces, so usually the link becomes active in a different space, but I don't know which one.

I believe that the problem is with Edge, since I cannot recreate it with Safari (Safari works as intended).

The *When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open
windows for the application* setting is turned ON.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem?

Comment: Seems like this is a bug - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/switch-focus-to-edge-when-a-link-is-opened-via-another-app/m-p/1024312

Comment: What do you mean by "the window is not focused"?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) -- https://superuser.com/questions/1779390/edge-window-does-not-focus-when-opening-external-link

Comment: This is how Edge works, but I’ve never investigated because I prefer this workflow

Comment: “Not focused” means the window/tab isn’t brought to the frontmost position, @Thinkr. It might help if you do a [quick search for terms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(computing)) you’re not familiar with.

Comment: Thinkr, I mean that Edge is opened (as in Edge menu in the menu bar) but the window itself is not focused (not on top/frontmost position as Allan said), nor is the Space changed.
@Allan I don't think this is how Edge is supposed to work. I've used it for years and I'm pretty sure this was not the default behaviour, otherwise I wouldn't have opened this post :)

Comment: It probably isn’t how it’s supposed to work, I just prefer this workfkow so I never investigated it.  I’ll look into it today.  I can tell you it has this same behavior for Edge on iOS/iPadOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in Edge 113.0.1774.35.